# Positioning rotated span css

Tags: html, css

I've got a `<span class="name">` next to an `<img>` inside a `<div>`. Inside this span I have some text which I want to turn 90 degrees. However, when I do this (as code suggests below) the span ends up in a somewhat weird position on top of the image.

In IE, the text doesn't rotate at all.

```
.name {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
}
```

Any suggestions as to how I solve this?

[image: In IE]
[image: In chrome]

Comment: also: can you give us the positioning css for the img/div, and the html so we can see? :)

Comment: Which IE version? Is the document in quirks or standards mode? Does the span "have layout"? (See http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed this on my own what I needed to do was put a fixed size on the span and then use `position:absolute;` to position it where I wanted it

Comment: I was going to suggest this. I think it would be the only reliable way of controlling the position.

Comment: tried it before but didn't set the size for the span so the span ended up jumping around depending on the amount of text in it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to fix it. But the reason it doesn't rotate in IE is that you are using "webkit" and "moz" to rotate - which are firefox-like-browser specific functions. You'll have to google for an IE-equivalent.

Comment: filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3); <-- is for the IE rotation

Comment: aha... sorry - my bad for not actually reading that line (or understanding that's what it was) :P